# Class pointer inside struct C++

Tags: c++, class, struct

The question is simple, I guess I cannot do this: (Im in the header file)

```
typedef struct {
     myclass *p;
     ...
 } mystruct;

class myclass {
     private:
          mystruct *s;
          ...
}
```

Because when the compiler reaches the struct it doesnt know what myclass is, but I cannot do the reverse either for the same reason:

```
class myclass {
     private:
          mystruct *s;
          ...
}

typedef struct {
     myclass *p;
     ...
 } mystruct;
```

How can I make that possible ? Im guessing there is some way to say the compiler "There is an struct called mystruct" before the class (2 example) so it knows that `mystruct *s` it's possible but I cant manage to do it right. Thanks

Comment: Please, no more `typedef struct { ...} xyz;`  In clean C++ you write `struct xyz { ...};` and the type is defined...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a **forward declaration**:

```
class myclass;

typedef struct {
     myclass *p;
     ...
 } mystruct;

class myclass {
     private:
          mystruct *s;
          ...
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `myclass` is a class when it first sees it.

---

Also, no need to typedef structs in C++. You can simply write:

```
struct mystruct {
     myclass *p;
     ...
};
```

Which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is possible to declare a pointer to a class that has not been defined yet. You need only to have "declared" the class (class myclass).

This is the general solution to define classes with cross-references.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, typedefs shouldn't be used anymore in modern C++ (there is better syntax). For structs just use:

```
struct mystruct {
...
}
```

Also maybe consider a redesign so that you don't have 2 types dependent on each other. If it's not possible, then as others have said forward declare the types before.

Comment: Sorry for that, Im comming from C and new to C++. Is typedef struct { ... } mystruct; just the same as struct mystruct { ... } ? Do they have any difference ?

Comment: @Ediolot They are exactly the same. In C++, you can simply write `struct mystruct {…};` and refer to the struct by its name: `mystruct`, no need to prepend `struct` before the name as in C. And consequently, no need to typedef it.

Comment: It's not the same, but they are similar. You will struggle to forward declare a typedef struct.